# Functional approach to a shopping basket

Tags: functional-programming

I was reading http://www.infoq.com/interviews/trelford-functional and trying to understand the alternative approach to OO.

> Q I see you’re doing a talk here at GOTOCon on functional
>   architecture, what is that? I thought all architectures were object
>   oriented?
>
> A Well, they’re not; I wanted to highlight the idea that your choice
>   of language and platform does affect your architecture in the way you
>   think; how picking a functional language or architecture can really
>   benefit the system.
>
> If I just take a simple example say we write a retail application, if
>   you think just about objects and mutation, then you would think when
>   you’re constructing a basket of items, as you add an item you'd
>   increase the quantity and if somebody returns an item or cancels an
>   item, you'd decrease the quantity, you’d be doing it wrong.
>
> With retail system, you need to track what’s actually been done so you
>   can detect fraud, it’s one of the key elements of the system; so you
>   actually add new values each this time, you never mutate.
>
> So just from one of the most basic systems that we interact with
>   everyday, functional immutable style is actually close to the
>   architecture you want.

If you were to adopt a more functional style wrt a shopping basket app, how would you be thinking about the problem? eg Would you still have a shopping basket object and rather than mutate its contents you'd create a new one or something?

Many thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a container data structure who's invariants modelled those of a basket (e.g. a [bag -like](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multiset/0.2.1/doc/html/Data-MultiSet.html) data type). The container would be persistent, so you could transparently roll back to older versions (to allow the user to undo actions, or save for a later visit).

By not destructively updating the basket, you get rollback, undo and persistence for free.

By using a richer data type, there is less book keeping to do, and thus less chance of bugs.

Comment: OK. Thx vm. Could you just explain how if you add an item to the basket? Eg, rather than, say, incrementing a counter, would you add an item to a collection or something like that? Though I can't see how that would give you a rollback capability unless you timestamped it,eg?

Comment: You'd add the item to the collection. Previous versions of the container would be logged in a history stack. No need for timestamping - just unwind the stack.

Comment: Is the container responsible for maintaining its own history? S

Comment: No. You'll record the history in a stack. The language will take care of sharing as much of the container between each version as necessary, so overhead is minimal.

Comment: Thx. Not sure what you mean when you say "the language". (Sorry if I'm being dumb). Can you give an example pseudocode or something? Thx again.